# How to parse this kind of output in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, string-formatting

I have output in following format

```
Image Name                     PID Services                                    
========================= ======== ============================================
System Idle Process              0 N/A                                         
services.exe                   436 N/A                                         
svchost.exe                    500 BrokerInfrastructure, DcomLaunch, LSM,      
                                   PlugPlay, Power, SystemEventsBroker         
vnetd.exe                    18504 NetBackup Legacy Network Service
```

I want to store the output in an array like this:

```
ar[0]=System Idle Process
ar[1]=0
ar[2]=N/A
```

I tried to split the string on the basis of whitespace but it didnt worked out. Can anyone suggest how to split this and get the desired output in c#

Comment: Please post your code and define "didn't worked out"

Comment: @Dave.. I tried to split on that basis of one white space like this 
formatedop = Regex.Split(item, @"\s{1}");
formatedop = formatedop.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

but i am not getting correct no of columns

Comment: If the image name will never contain a number, you could use this: split string in whitespace and walk through all parts until number found. Maybe you could use a regex, which also separates on the number.

Comment: @royalTS..I used regex but i am getting output in the following manner

ar[0]=System
ar[1]=Idle
ar[2]=Process
ar[3]=0
ar[4]=N/A

Comment: Seems like you have fixed width fields (that get padded), you could define the width based on the `=` signs, and then just substring them like that?

Comment: @Icepickle..can you please show a small example?

Comment: @Icepickle.. thanks for the suggestion. I tried on that basis of padding and now i am getting the output.

Comment: @Developer Cool, good that you found the solution on your own, however, I did add an answer still on how you could do it (without the use of arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the information you are receiving has a fixed width output, so, you can just use `string.Substring` to get each time a part of the string as you want.

You could read the items in your input like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<ProcessItem> GetItemsFromText(string text) {
    var lines = text.Split( new [] { "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
    ProcessItem current = null;
    Console.WriteLine( "Lines found: {0}", lines.Length );
    // skip first 2 lines (header and = signs)
    for (int i = 2; i < lines.Length; i++) {
        var name = lines[i].Substring( 0, 25 ).Trim();
        var pid = lines[i].Substring( 26, 8 ).Trim();
        var services = lines[i].Substring( 35 ).Trim();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( name ) ) {
            if (current != null) {
                yield return current;
            }
            current = new ProcessItem {
                Name = name,
                Pid = pid,
                Services = services
            };
        } else {
            current.Services += ' ' + services;
        }
    }
    if (current != null) {
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

This version would also acknowledge that you have multi line items, and would send back a custom class `ProcessItem` that looks like the following

```
public class ProcessItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pid { get;set; }
    public string Services { get;set; }
}
```

A running version of the code you can find back in this [.netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T2auB0)

Comment: That's a nice touch to return the data as an enumerable list of objects rather than a two dimensional array, but I think this would be an even better answer if you explained why this is a good idea.

Comment: @RobinBennett You are right that I might be able to improve the answer by explaining, but maybe there is a reason he wants is as an array. I guess the OP can decide if he wants more info :)

Answer (score 1):

```
use substring on the basis of padding 

formatedop[0] = item.Substring(0, 25);
formatedop[1] = item.Substring(25, 10);
formatedop[2] = item.Substring(35, 40);

it will give the result
```